# Tinymce justbioil image not uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, image-uploading, justboil.me

I am using justboil plugin in tinymce for image uploading. I am having an issue with image uploading, When I upload image it got stuck on “Upload in progress” message. In network tab(console) error is “The Upload process had not started, or started, but had not finished yet, or your browser could not reach the remote server.”. It was working fine before yesterday but now it is not working. Upload function of controller Uploader is also not working if I access it directly through URL.
I have thoroughly read http://justboil.me/ and [How to fix Jbimages plugin for Tinymce 3.x not uploading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818639/how-to-fix-jbimages-plugin-for-tinymce-3-x-not-uploading-image) but found no answer.
Can anybody please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I found solution to this problem accidentally. I just remove controller name from URL while calling upload function and set uploader controller as default controller in routes.php. Now its working fine